# AngularJS autocomplete from web service

Tags: angularjs, html, api

I'm using REST Countries web service and I want to have an autocomplete feature when user is starting to type in input field, and when some country was selected to display an info about it. Want to do it with factories or maybe a directive, don't know what solution is the best
Here is what I have for now:

REST service link: https://restcountries.eu/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="CountriesController">
    <h3 id="title">Countries Database</h3>
    <input type="text" id="countrySearch" ng-model="selected" typeahead="country for country in countries | limitTo:8" />

    <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

**Template:**

```
<div ng-controller="CountriesController">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="country in countries" id="countryInfo">
        <p><b>Country:</b> {{country.name}}</p>
        <p><b>Native Name:</b> {{country.nativeName}}</p>
        <p><b>Capital:</b> {{country.capital}}</p>
        <p><b>Region:</b> {{country.region}}</p>
        <p><b>Subregion:</b> {{country.subregion}}</p>
        <p><b>Borders:</b> {{borders}}</p>
        <p><b>Languages:</b> {{languages}}</p>
        <p><b>Population:</b> {{country.population}} people</p>
        <p><b>Area:</b> {{country.area}} sq.km</p>
        <p><b>Currencies:</b> {{currencies}}</p>
        <p><b>Timezones:</b> {{timezones}}</p>
        <p><b>Calling Code:</b> +{{callingCodes}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('CountriesController', function ($scope, CountriesFactory) {

CountriesFactory.getCountry().then(function (data) {
    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $scope.countries = data;
    console.log($scope.countries);

    $scope.timezones = data[0].timezones.toString();
    $scope.languages = data[0].languages.toString();
    $scope.currencies = data[0].currencies.toString();
    $scope.borders = data[0].borders.toString();
    $scope.callingCodes = data[0].callingCodes.toString();
});

});
```

**Factory:**

```
app.factory('CountriesFactory', function ($http, $q) {
return {
    getCountry: function () {
        var input = $('#countrySearch').val();
        var request = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/';
        var url = request + input;

        return $http.get(url);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: what error do you get? can you do a print screen with the error in console ?

Comment: @user2232187  just this, can't resolve it. GET https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/ 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [bootstrap UI's autocomplete widget](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)

Look at [the source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js) to see how it is implemented

Comment: It's already implemented in my code, but it doesn't work with this service through factories

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [rest countries](https://restcountries.eu/) here you can see the example how to get the rest countries like: [example](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/aruba)
The [restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name](http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name) is not working because they don't expose that page.

Try to make sure you have something into input. Try to check if

```
$('#countrySearch').val();
```

is not null or empty first.